# Pitch drop experiment with (poly/mono)crystal

Tags: crystals, viscosity, amorphous-solids

In 1927 [a piece of pitch was placed in a funnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_drop_experiment) and since then pitch flowed at rate of about 1 drop per 10 years.

Obviously we can repeat experiment with any amorphous solid. Viscosity of water is about 10^-2 poise, for pitch it's 2 * 10^9 poise, and ~10^20 for glass.

So for a piece of glass we would see about 1 drop every trillion (10^12) years.

But what if we use a monocrystal, for example an ideal diamond? Characteristic bond energy is several eV, while heat energy of air molecule is some 10^-2 eV - 2 orders of magnitude less. Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution says that one in every 10^(some tens) air molecule would be fast enough to break this bond and produce dislocation. The same process would cause dislocations to appear inside the crystal.

Diamond is most stable state for graphite so dislocations number would not grow till it turns into graphite, but for a given temperature there will be some equilibrium level of dislocations. And the fluctuation of the same heat based nature would move dislocations around and preferred way of their movement would lower diamond center of gravity and make it fit funnels shape (as it would lower potential energy of the system).

So basically we can expect every monocrystal to behave like polycrystal on extremely long time-ranges and every policrystal to "flow" down and make drops.

Can we estimate the time per drop for 1 kg of steel and 1 kg of ideal diamond in immutable funnel at room temperature? Would it be 10^1000 years or 10^(10^100) years or did I miss something and it would not flow at all?

(Let's ignore chemical processes like oxidation and [fusion/decay of elements at 10^1500 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_far_future))

Comment: [Deformation Mechanism Maps](https://defmech.engineering.dartmouth.edu/) is an excellent online resource discussing flow regimes and kinetics. It has creep data for both metals and ceramics; the Si/Ge content could be useful as a surrogate for diamond. Note that dislocation movement is only one  regime; at lower stresses, viscous diffusional flow dominates.

Comment: I doubt that there is a guarantee that every system has to have a viscosity. The theory for that is classical, while crystalline systems are following the laws of quantum mechanics at low temperatures. This sounds more like a case of overextrapolation of theory that was developed for highly viscous materials.

Comment: The most reasonable framework is that all materials creep to some degree at all temperatures, although the rate may be negligible. I have yet to hear about a chunk of material that doesn't contain thermal vacancies, which is one of the mechanisms enabling viscous flow under a load (including the self-weight). [Related resource in the context of geology.](https://ocw.tudelft.nl/wp-content/uploads/Principles_of_Rock_Mechanics_Ch8.pdf) The question basically reduces to the prefactor and activation energy of the associated [Arrhenius equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation).

Comment: @Chemomechanics  Superconductors and superfluids are displaying completely non-classical behavior below their critical temperature. I have not seen a quantum theory of viscosity, yet, but I wouldn't rule out that it's different from the classical counterpart.